# viewport stuck with wrong fps

Tags: 3d-view

Unfortunately I cannot upload the file as I am using a bought model.

I have the animation set at 24 fps. In the viewport it plays twice as slow - 1 second takes 2 seconds to play.

Note: this is not an issue of blender being slow and not loading fast enough - there is not red fps number on the left side when playing it.

I checked the Time Remapping values and they are 100:100 as they should be by default, so I really don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In the viewport on top left you can see the current fps is it constantly 24 or it drops down?

Comment: Have you tried appending the model to a new file?

Comment: appending did the trick. god knows! thanks!